# php var as executable name of the array+cell

Tags: php, arrays, cell, var

What is the proper syntax for $var? I want to use it as designation of the yet nonexistent  array's cell (// how in code) :

```
$array = array (
    array("folder" => "november", "name" => "1.jpg"),
    array("folder" => "december", "name" => "1.jpg")
);
$var = "$picture['folder']"; // how to make it not a string value and use it in foreach cycle

foreach ($array as $picture) { // only here comes subarray
    echo $var;
    echo '<br>';
}

/* should be
november
december
*/
```

P.S. This is a simple gallery-calendar task, we echo image path...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for misunderstanding... I want to use $var = "$subArray['folder']" not as string value, but as real array cell... kind of link to it

Comment: variable variable?  `$$var`.... where `$var = hello;` and `$$var = 'taco';` means that.... `$hello === 'taco'`

Comment: In my example I have two statements. If I have $_GET['folder'], I don't use array's 'folder' value (and I don't receive it from database). But if I haven't $_GET['folder'], I should receive 'folder' from database, put it into array's 'folder' cell and use it in foreach statement. I know I can do it in another way but I want to know how can I use $var as a name of the nonexistent array, which will appear lately.

Comment: what.  `$folder = isset($_GET['folder'] ? $_GET['folder'] : ______;` where the blank is whatever you use if you don't get folder from db

Comment: Yeah, I know, but It's one more operation in each cycle. The task is to set $var before foreach cycle... $_GET['folder'] - we have only one folder value, from db I can receive a dozen of values (different folders for each image)

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you're trying to say.  I'm sorry...  Show me the data in the array that you have and show me examples of what you want to end up with. and the value in `$_GET['folder']`

Comment: My array is in the first comment as example. It contains folders november, december... foreach cycle forms image path 'november/1.jpg' and 'december/1.jpg' - it's a folder and name cells of the array we receive from db... but if we have $_GET['folder']='april', we should form path 'april/1.jpg' and 'april/1.jpg' - and in that case we don't have 'folder' cell in array (we don't send a query for it)...... in foreach cycle when we type echo $var should be perceived as echo $subArray['folder']

Comment: OH..  do your loop... `foreach ($array as $index => $value) { `  and then use `$value` or `$array[$index]`

Comment: or.... `echo $var . '/' . $subArray['folder'];`   ?  or.... `echo $subArray['name'] . '/' . $subArray['folder'];`... I'm trying on drunk american english at 6:30am.  I'm trying.

Comment: to figure out yourself, just do:  `foreach ($array as $index => $subArray) { echo "$index\n"; var_dump($subArray); echo "----------------\n\n"; }`

Comment: no, I only echoing image path... this is a simple gallery-calendar task, we echo 1) specific month to show images of april, for example ($_GET['folder']) or 2) random images from any months in db (array['folder'])...

Comment: here is the thing... 1) `foreach ($array as $subArray) { echo $_GET["folder"]."/".$subArray["name"]; }` 2) `foreach ($array as $subArray) { echo $subArray["folder"]."/".$subArray["name"]; }`... do you see the differnece? it's only a first part of the path... that's why I should use $var instead

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what you are looking for...???

But this is everything you have:

```
$array = array(
       array("folder" => "november", "name" => "1.jpg"),
       array("folder" => "december", "name" => "1.jpg")
   );

print "<pre>"; 

foreach ($array as $index => $subArray)
{
   print "\$index = $index   <br/>";
   print "\$index[$index]['folder'] = {$array[$index]['folder']} = {$subArray['folder']}  <br/>"; 
   print "\$index[$index]['folder'] = {$array[$index]['name']}   = {$subArray['name']}    <br/>"; 
   print "<br/>";
}   

print "</pre>"; 


/*

$index = 0   
$index[0]['folder'] = november = november  
$index[0]['folder'] = 1.jpg   = 1.jpg    

$index = 1   
$index[1]['folder'] = december = december  
$index[1]['folder'] = 1.jpg   = 1.jpg    


*/
```

Comment: If I have $_GET['folder'] I don't receive 'folder' from DB, so array hasn't folder key in this case, only name... and foreach should use $_GET['folder']

Comment: I do not understand you.  **Show me the data you have.**  Update your question.  Show me.  `var_dump($_GET);`  and   `var_dump($from_the_database);`